# Autocomplete com campos dinâmicos

Tags: jquery, asp, autocompletar

Tenho uma tabela com os campos (produto, qtde, pUnit e pTotal) o campo produto é autocomplete.

Quando entra na página, ja existe uma linha, por isso o autocomplete funciona perfeito.

Andei lendo que como as novas linhas não existe no DOM, precisa fazer algo para ele entender e aceitar a nova linha.

Pois bem, já fiz de tudo, mas nada adiantou.

Adiciona nova linha

```
    var numProd         = $("#NumProd").val();
    var numProdAtual    = parseInt(numProd) + 1;

    var newRow = $('<tr id="tr-'+numProdAtual+'">');

    var cols = "";

    //cols += '<tr id="tr-'+numProdAtual+'">';

    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<input type="text" name="dProdutoVenda['+numProdAtual+']" data-id-reg="'+numProdAtual+'" class="form-control error input-desc-prod" required="required" autocomplete="off" />';
    cols += '</td>';

    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<input type="text" name="qProdutoVenda['+numProdAtual+']" data-id-reg="'+numProdAtual+'" class="form-control error text-right" required="required" onBlur="AtualizaValorProd("+numProdAtual+");" />';
    cols += '</td>';

    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<input type="text" name="vUnitProdutoVenda['+numProdAtual+']" data-id-reg="'+numProdAtual+'" class="form-control text-right" readonly />';
    cols += '</td>';

    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<input type="text" name="vTotProdutoVenda['+numProdAtual+']" data-id-reg="'+numProdAtual+'" class="form-control text-right" readonly />';
    cols += '</td>';

    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-circle exc-prod" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>';
    cols += '</td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#table-vendas-produtos").append(newRow);
```

Reconhecer a nova linha

```
    $(".input-desc-prod:last").focus().autocomplete("produtos-procura-descricao.asp", { 
        minChars: 1 //Número mínimo de caracteres para aparecer a lista
      , matchContains: true //Aparecer somente os que tem relação ao valor digitado
      , scrollHeight: 230 //Altura da lista dos nomes
      , selectFirst: true //Vim o primeiro da lista selecionado
      , mustMatch: true //Caso não existir na lista, remover o valor
      , delay: 0 //Tempo para aparecer a lista para 0, por padrão vem 200
    });
```

Também já tentei assim

```
    newRow.find('.input-desc-prod').autocomplete("produtos-procura-descricao.asp", { 
        minChars: 1 //Número mínimo de caracteres para aparecer a lista
      , matchContains: true //Aparecer somente os que tem relação ao valor digitado
      , scrollHeight: 230 //Altura da lista dos nomes
      , selectFirst: true //Vim o primeiro da lista selecionado
      , mustMatch: true //Caso não existir na lista, remover o valor
      , delay: 0 //Tempo para aparecer a lista para 0, por padrão vem 200
    });
```

Também já tentei outros autocomplete e não deu certo.

Será que alguém poderia dar uma luz no fim do túnel?

Obrigado

rodando, rodando e achei a solução, funcionou, vou deixar registrado, pode ser que ajude alguém.

```
$at('#table-vendas-produtos').find('.input-desc-prod').autocomplete("produtos-procura-descricao.asp", {
```

Comment: Marque a pergunta como respondida

Comment: Sou novo aqui, como faço isso?

Comment: Tente você mesmo adicionar a resposta a ela, aí vc marca ela como respondida. Se não for possível, acho q algum moderaror precisaria fechá-la...

Comment: @RonaldoBueno você tem a opção de responder sua própria resposta caso ache uma solução.